# KeystoneJS: How to filter relationship, base on another relationship?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

Model code:

```
const Item = new keystone.List('Item')

Item.add({
  name: { type: String, initial: true },
  channel: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Channel', initial: true },
  program: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Program', initial: true, filters: { channel: ':channel' } }
})
```

1 channel can have many programs, and 1 program can have many items.

When creating an Item, I want to list only the programs from the selected channel. If no channel is selected, then the program list should be empty.

Is it possible ? it is not working yet on my side.

Thanks in advance.